# Getting SimpleXML error

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to echo the text that is in between the quotes in `<head_1 data="Superhero"/>`

The XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nowplaying version="1.1">
    <playing_now>
        <rbds_text data="SUPERHERO by Family Force 5"/>
        <result>
            <type data="song"/>
            <head_1 data="Superhero"/>
            <head_2 data="Family Force 5"/>
            <head_url data="song/Family_Force_5/Superhero.html"/>
            <foot_1 data="III.V - EP"/>
            <foot_2 data="Family Force 5"/>
            <foot_url data="album/Family_Force_5/III.V_-_EP.html"/>
            <image_50 data="/images/music/thumbs/familyforce5-iiivep.jpg"/>
            <image_200 data="/images/music/familyforce5-iiivep.jpg"/>
        </result>
    </playing_now>
</nowplaying>
```

My current PHP file looks like this, but I'm getting an error:

```
<?php
include 'playing-now/api.html';

$nowplaying = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

echo $nowplaying->playing_now->result->head_1;"
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $nowplaying->playing_now->result->head_1['data'];
```

If you're getting any errors, it might be on the names. You should be able to escape them like this:

```
echo $nowplaying->{'playing_now'}->result->{'head_1'}['data'];
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the error I'm getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in playing-now/api.html on line 1

Comment: I would check playing-now/api.html, it looks like you maybe have a <?php tag in there when it shouldn't be. It may have an html extension, but you're using php's include so it will process the file as php.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have any control over what is in that file...any other suggestions?